# Including <string> causes 'redefinition' error of std-lib functions

Tags: c++, xcode

I am porting a quite large C/C++ project to Mac with XCode. Some C++ classes import `string` or `vector`. This causes some strange errors reporting redefinition of several std functions. For example the compiler reports `redefinition of 'std::__is_integral'` in `<type_traits>`.

I don't get any other errors and I definitely don't overwrite any of these std-functions. Also the error vanishes when I comment the include of `string`.

What might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that somewhere in the C++ code - which I inherited for this project - there was a redefinition of `bool`. `bool` was redefined as `int`. Therefore in the `type_traits` header (and some other std-lib headers) there were duplicate method definitions of generic methods that hat a `bool` and an `int` generic parameter.

For example in type_traits there is:

```
template <> struct __is_integral<bool> : public true_type {};
```

and

```
template <> struct __is_integral<int> : public true_type {};
```

As `bool` was redefined as int both methods had the same signature and I got this `redefinition of...` error.

Comment: Please don't refer to C++ as "C/C++". This is Simply Wrong (R).

Comment: You're right. Sorry. The project has C and C++ code but the described problem only affects the C++ code. (I edited the answer)